# Why does my variable not increase when I add to it

Tags: vb.net

So I have a variable called SquareNumber and that is what determines what square your character is on (I am making a snakes and ladders game for homework.) Each time the button is pressed, it creates two random numbers and they are added together as a new variable that is called Total. The SquareNumber gets the Total added to it. I then have a long list of code that should make the previous label that had it's colour changed return to black, and a new label have it's colour changed depending on the value of the SquareNumber. However each time I click the button, the square number is always equal to the total. For example the current total is 5, then the SquareNumber gets added 5. Next lets say the next total is 7, then the SquareNumber should get 7 added to it and be 12 (5 + 7 = 12) but it just says 7. :( Any help is appreciated. Thanks :)

```
'Creating random numbers and displaying them as labels.

    Dim SquareNumber1 As Integer
    Dim Total As Integer
    Dim RandomGen As New Random
    Dim RandomInt1 As Integer
    RandomInt1 = RandomGen.Next(2, 7)
    Player1DiceRoll1.Text = CStr(RandomInt1)
    Dim RandomInt2 As Integer
    RandomInt2 = RandomGen.Next(2, 7)
    Player1DiceRoll2.Text = CStr(RandomInt2)
    Total = RandomInt2 + RandomInt1
    Player1OutputLabel.Text = CStr(Total)
    SquareNumber1 = SquareNumber1 + Total

    'Change a the last label back to white.
    If Label1.ForeColor = Color.Lime Then
        Label1.ForeColor = Color.Black
    ElseIf Label2.Forecolor = Color.Lime Then
        Label2.ForeColor = Color.Black
    ElseIf Label3.ForeColor = Color.Lime Then
        Label3.ForeColor = Color.Black
    ElseIf Label4.ForeColor = Color.Lime Then
        Label4.ForeColor = Color.Black
    ElseIf Label5.ForeColor = Color.Lime Then
        Label5.ForeColor = Color.Black
    ElseIf Label6.ForeColor = Color.Lime Then
        Label6.ForeColor = Color.Black
    ElseIf Label7.ForeColor = Color.Lime Then
        Label7.ForeColor = Color.Black
    ElseIf Label8.ForeColor = Color.Lime Then
        Label8.ForeColor = Color.Black
    ElseIf Label9.ForeColor = Color.Lime Then
        Label9.ForeColor = Color.Black
    ElseIf Label10.ForeColor = Color.Lime Then
        Label10.ForeColor = Color.Black
    ElseIf Label11.ForeColor = Color.Lime Then
        Label11.ForeColor = Color.Black
    ElseIf Label12.ForeColor = Color.Lime Then
        Label12.ForeColor = Color.Black
    ElseIf Label13.ForeColor = Color.Lime Then
        Label13.ForeColor = Color.Black
    ElseIf Label14.ForeColor = Color.Lime Then
        Label14.ForeColor = Color.Black
    ElseIf Label15.ForeColor = Color.Lime Then
        Label15.ForeColor = Color.Black
    ElseIf Label16.ForeColor = Color.Lime Then
        Label16.ForeColor = Color.Black
    ElseIf Label17.ForeColor = Color.Lime Then
        Label17.ForeColor = Color.Black
    ElseIf Label18.ForeColor = Color.Lime Then
        Label18.ForeColor = Color.Black
    ElseIf Label19.ForeColor = Color.Lime Then
        Label19.ForeColor = Color.Black
    ElseIf Label20.ForeColor = Color.Lime Then
        Label20.ForeColor = Color.Black
    ElseIf Label21.ForeColor = Color.Lime Then
        Label21.ForeColor = Color.Black
    ElseIf Label22.ForeColor = Color.Lime Then
        Label22.ForeColor = Color.Black
    ElseIf Label23.ForeColor = Color.Lime Then
        Label23.ForeColor = Color.Black
    ElseIf Label24.ForeColor = Color.Lime Then
        Label24.ForeColor = Color.Black
    ElseIf Label25.ForeColor = Color.Lime Then
        Label25.ForeColor = Color.Black
    ElseIf Label26.ForeColor = Color.Lime Then
        Label26.ForeColor = Color.Black
    ElseIf Label27.ForeColor = Color.Lime Then
        Label27.ForeColor = Color.Black
    ElseIf Label28.ForeColor = Color.Lime Then
        Label28.ForeColor = Color.Black
    ElseIf Label29.ForeColor = Color.Lime Then
        Label29.ForeColor = Color.Black
    ElseIf Label30.ForeColor = Color.Lime Then
        Label30.ForeColor = Color.Black
    ElseIf Label31.ForeColor = Color.Lime Then
        Label31.ForeColor = Color.Black
    ElseIf Label32.ForeColor = Color.Lime Then
        Label32.ForeColor = Color.Black
    ElseIf Label33.ForeColor = Color.Lime Then
        Label33.ForeColor = Color.Black
    ElseIf Label34.ForeColor = Color.Lime Then
        Label34.ForeColor = Color.Black
    ElseIf Label35.ForeColor = Color.Lime Then
        Label35.ForeColor = Color.Black
    ElseIf Label36.ForeColor = Color.Lime Then
        Label36.ForeColor = Color.Black
    ElseIf Label37.ForeColor = Color.Lime Then
        Label37.ForeColor = Color.Black
    ElseIf Label38.ForeColor = Color.Lime Then
        Label38.ForeColor = Color.Black
    ElseIf Label39.ForeColor = Color.Lime Then
        Label39.ForeColor = Color.Black
    ElseIf Label40.ForeColor = Color.Lime Then
        Label40.ForeColor = Color.Black
    ElseIf Label41.ForeColor = Color.Lime Then
        Label41.ForeColor = Color.Black
    ElseIf Label42.ForeColor = Color.Lime Then
        Label42.ForeColor = Color.Black
    ElseIf Label43.ForeColor = Color.Lime Then
        Label43.ForeColor = Color.Black
    ElseIf Label44.ForeColor = Color.Lime Then
        Label44.ForeColor = Color.Black
    ElseIf Label45.ForeColor = Color.Lime Then
        Label45.ForeColor = Color.Black
    ElseIf Label46.ForeColor = Color.Lime Then
        Label46.ForeColor = Color.Black
    ElseIf Label47.ForeColor = Color.Lime Then
        Label47.ForeColor = Color.Black
    ElseIf Label48.ForeColor = Color.Lime Then
        Label48.ForeColor = Color.Black
    ElseIf Label49.ForeColor = Color.Lime Then
        Label49.ForeColor = Color.Black
    End If

    'Changing the new label to the right coloUr.
    If SquareNumber1 = 1 Then
        Label1.ForeColor = Color.Lime
    ElseIf SquareNumber1 = 2 Then
        Label2.ForeColor = Color.Lime
    ElseIf SquareNumber1 = 3 Then
        Label3.ForeColor = Color.Lime
    ElseIf SquareNumber1 = 4 Then
        Label4.ForeColor = Color.Lime
    ElseIf SquareNumber1 = 5 Then
        Label5.ForeColor = Color.Lime
    ElseIf SquareNumber1 = 6 Then
        Label6.ForeColor = Color.Lime
    ElseIf SquareNumber1 = 7 Then
        Label7.ForeColor = Color.Lime
    ElseIf SquareNumber1 = 8 Then
        Label8.ForeColor = Color.Lime
    ElseIf SquareNumber1 = 9 Then
        Label9.ForeColor = Color.Lime
    ElseIf SquareNumber1 = 10 Then
        Label10.ForeColor = Color.Lime
    ElseIf SquareNumber1 = 11 Then
        Label11.ForeColor = Color.Lime
    ElseIf SquareNumber1 = 12 Then
        Label12.ForeColor = Color.Lime
    ElseIf SquareNumber1 = 13 Then
        Label13.ForeColor = Color.Lime
    ElseIf SquareNumber1 = 14 Then
        Label14.ForeColor = Color.Lime
    ElseIf SquareNumber1 = 15 Then
        Label15.ForeColor = Color.Lime
    ElseIf SquareNumber1 = 16 Then
        Label16.ForeColor = Color.Lime
    ElseIf SquareNumber1 = 17 Then
        Label17.ForeColor = Color.Lime
    ElseIf SquareNumber1 = 18 Then
        Label18.ForeColor = Color.Lime
    ElseIf SquareNumber1 = 19 Then
        Label19.ForeColor = Color.Lime
    ElseIf SquareNumber1 = 20 Then
        Label20.ForeColor = Color.Lime
    ElseIf SquareNumber1 = 21 Then
        Label21.ForeColor = Color.Lime
    ElseIf SquareNumber1 = 22 Then
        Label22.ForeColor = Color.Lime
    ElseIf SquareNumber1 = 23 Then
        Label23.ForeColor = Color.Lime
    ElseIf SquareNumber1 = 24 Then
        Label24.ForeColor = Color.Lime
    ElseIf SquareNumber1 = 25 Then
        Label25.ForeColor = Color.Lime
    ElseIf SquareNumber1 = 26 Then
        Label26.ForeColor = Color.Lime
    ElseIf SquareNumber1 = 27 Then
        Label27.ForeColor = Color.Lime
    ElseIf SquareNumber1 = 28 Then
        Label28.ForeColor = Color.Lime
    ElseIf SquareNumber1 = 29 Then
        Label29.ForeColor = Color.Lime
    ElseIf SquareNumber1 = 30 Then
        Label30.ForeColor = Color.Lime
    ElseIf SquareNumber1 = 31 Then
        Label31.ForeColor = Color.Lime
    ElseIf SquareNumber1 = 32 Then
        Label32.ForeColor = Color.Lime
    ElseIf SquareNumber1 = 33 Then
        Label33.ForeColor = Color.Lime
    ElseIf SquareNumber1 = 34 Then
        Label34.ForeColor = Color.Lime
    ElseIf SquareNumber1 = 35 Then
        Label35.ForeColor = Color.Lime
    ElseIf SquareNumber1 = 36 Then
        Label36.ForeColor = Color.Lime
    ElseIf SquareNumber1 = 37 Then
        Label37.ForeColor = Color.Lime
    ElseIf SquareNumber1 = 38 Then
        Label38.ForeColor = Color.Lime
    ElseIf SquareNumber1 = 39 Then
        Label39.ForeColor = Color.Lime
    ElseIf SquareNumber1 = 40 Then
        Label40.ForeColor = Color.Lime
    ElseIf SquareNumber1 = 41 Then
        Label41.ForeColor = Color.Lime
    ElseIf SquareNumber1 = 42 Then
        Label42.ForeColor = Color.Lime
    ElseIf SquareNumber1 = 43 Then
        Label43.ForeColor = Color.Lime
    ElseIf SquareNumber1 = 44 Then
        Label44.ForeColor = Color.Lime
    ElseIf SquareNumber1 = 45 Then
        Label45.ForeColor = Color.Lime
    ElseIf SquareNumber1 = 46 Then
        Label46.ForeColor = Color.Lime
    ElseIf SquareNumber1 = 47 Then
        Label47.ForeColor = Color.Lime
    ElseIf SquareNumber1 = 48 Then
        Label48.ForeColor = Color.Lime
    ElseIf SquareNumber1 >= 49 Then
        Label49.ForeColor = Color.Lime
        Dim Win As Integer = MsgBox("Well done, Mordor (Player1) won the game!", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
        If Win = DialogResult.OK Then
            End
        Else
            Button1.Enabled = False
            Button2.Enabled = False
        End If
    ElseIf SquareNumber1 <= 0 Then
        SquareNumber1 = 1
        Label1.ForeColor = Color.Lime
    End If
```

Comment: Have you tried to declare SquareNumber as static? Besides that, the variable must be declared in class level, not in the method

Comment: Every time you enter this event that the Button is clicked you create a empty SquareNumber1. So adding Total to it will get you the value of total SquareNumber1 = 0 + total.  You need to figure out a way to keep the value of SquareNumber1. You could write it into exel someware, or make the variable global, just to mention 2 methods

Comment: Thank the gods for your help! All I needed was to delcare SquareNumber as static! I really love you guys!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to skin this cat (or snake.)
As @GEnGEr mentioned, you can store the value in a sheet and read from it at the start of the sub and then write to it at the end.

Or you can not exit the sub until the game is finished.

Us a do while or a do until loop that checks for win or loss conditions and only exit the sub when one or the other condition are met. Probably throw in an "I quit" button also or something to exit early.

There are other ways but these 2 are easy starting points.

Answer (score 0):

This is off topic; but I wanted to show you a simpler approach.

```
Sub Example()
Static x As Integer     ' Static retains values between calls.
Dim Total As Integer

    ' Update old square.
    Me.Controls("Label" & CStr(SquareNumber1)).ForeColor = Color.Black

    ' Roll dice.
    SquareNumber1 = SquareNumber1 + Total

    ' Update new square.
    Me.Controls("Label" & CStr(SquareNumber1)).ForeColor = Color.Lime
End Sub
```

This code uses a property of your [form](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Overview-of-forms-Form-controls-and-ActiveX-controls-on-a-worksheet-15ba7e28-8d7f-42ab-9470-ffb9ab94e7c2?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB&fromAR=1) called Controls.   Controls is an array.  Each element in the array is a control on your form.

With this method you can directly access the control you wish to update (by its name), without the need to check every square in the game.

If you added 10 new squares to the game your code would continue to work, without any changes (as long as they followed the same naming convention).

**ANSWER**

See comments from @RicardoPontual & @EnGEr for a working answer.

Comment: Who knew you could make all this code into just one line! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

not quite sure which language you're in since it quite similar to VBA but there's something I can't actually grasp

What follows is for a VBA environment assuming:

- you're running the game from inside a userform
- this is the code for its button click event handler
- `Random` is some class of yours
- `Color` is some class/enum of yours

but I guess that should yours not be VBA, still some main coding solutions could apply

here's the code to be placed in the userform code pane:

```
Dim SquareNumber1 As Integer '<-- userform scoped variable
Dim iLastLabel As Long '<-- userform scoped variable

Sub Button_Click()

    'Creating random numbers and displaying them as labels.

    Dim Total As Integer
    Dim RandomGen As New Random 
    Dim RandomInt1 As Integer
    RandomInt1 = RandomGen.Next(2, 7)
    Player1DiceRoll1.Text = CStr(RandomInt1)
    Dim RandomInt2 As Integer
    RandomInt2 = RandomGen.Next(2, 7)
    Player1DiceRoll2.Text = CStr(RandomInt2)
    Total = RandomInt2 + RandomInt1
    Player1OutputLabel.Text = CStr(Total)
    SquareNumber1 = SquareNumber1 + Total

    With Me '<-- reference to Userform
        'Change a the last label back to white.
        If iLastLabel > 0 Then .Controls("Label" & iLbl).ForeColor = Color.Black

        'Changing the new label to the right colour.
        Select Case SquareNumber1
            Case Is <= 0
                SquareNumber1 = 1
                Label1.ForeColor = Color.Lime
                iLastLabel = 1

            Case Is <= 48
                .Controls("Label" & SquareNumber1).ForeColor = Color.Lime
                iLastLabel = SquareNumber1

            Case Else
                Label49.ForeColor = Color.Lime
                Dim Win As Integer = MsgBox("Well done, Mordor (Player1) won the game!", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
                If Win = DialogResult.OK Then Exit Sub
                Button1.Enabled = False
                Button2.Enabled = False
        End Select
    End With
End Sub
```